# Preventing theft of data on remotely deployed servers exposed to physical access

Tags: linux, security

I am trying to think of a way to secure Linux servers that are exposed to physical access. My specific platform are small form factor Linux servers on a PC Engines brand [alix2d13](http://www.pcengines.ch/alix2d13.htm) mother board. The small size presents an additional risk of removal from the premises by an attacker.

Assuming there is physical access to the server:

1) ROOT-PASSWORD: You connect a console cable to the server and you get a prompt for a password. If you don’t know the password you can restart the machine in single user mode and reset the password. Voilà, you get root access.

In order to secure the above you insert a password on the [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) menu so when server is restarted in order to enter single user mode you have to provide the GRUB password.

2) GRUB_PASSWORD. If you shut down the machine, get the hard drive out and mount it on another workstation you will be able to browse the `/boot` directory which contains the grub.cfg file inside which you can find the GRUB password. You can either change the GRUB password or delete it.

Obviously when we talk about big production machines most probably there won't be any physical access and apart from that, even if someone gets physical access to the server he won't shut it down.

What are possible solutions to prevent data theft on servers that are physically easy to steal?

The way I see it, one way or another access to the contained data can be obtained.

Comment: Unless you want to be around to enter a decryption password each time it boots, there is not much you can do. Decryption could be done by communicating with a network service which is only available as long as it is on the proper network. That's not very secure, but sufficient to cover the case where the thief doesn't try to access the data while on site. But a targeted attacker could even steal the machine without powering it off. I suppose it wouldn't take a lot of battery capacity to keep it powered for a few minutes.

Comment: Bury it in concrete. That will certainly prevent theft!

Comment: It's not really clear what the threat model is. You want a device that is invulnerable to physical compromise? That's going to be very complex and expensive. Computers are not vaults. If you want a vault, you need a vault.

Comment: The question title is very bad.  The question itself is probably a duplicate, as every sysadmin knows that if you have physical access to a system then it is compromisable.  Lastly, your question doesn't appear to relate to a professional sysadmin in a production environment (as no-one would deploy this...)

Comment: Another way to access a server is by exploiting a weakness in drivers loaded through hot-plugging. So you should prevent access to all external ports (especially USB), too AND disable hot-plugging and/or unneeded drivers where possible.

Comment: @BlueCompute The question can arise in a professional environment as well, so it should stay here.

Comment: @BlueCompute I think the question is very clear, i have placed forth various ways where a linux system can be compromised and i asked a way to prevent them. Regarding production  environment and if someone will deploy this..well...in the previous company i used to work as sysadmin, we used to deploy those embedded mini servers on vessels for firewalling, reporting, traffic monitoring e.t.c It has allways been an issue for us that someone could use the methods i mentioned and gain access to the system and steal our code which performs all the tasks a mention above.

Comment: @giomanda why do you think someone is better off stealing your code instead of making their own ? Stealing something physically isn't trivial (and has much greater risks than online hacking), and unless your code is something you can't do without years of R&D, no one is going to bother stealing it physically.

Comment: @André It is very time consuming to explain the relevant business area and that would be off topic. If you read the 7th comment where i state where these questions were arisen from i think you will think off some reason why. Simply placed, when there is competition, other people try to find out how you do stuff, and why your linux blackbox performs the same functions as yours much better. It happens that your competitor might have your blackbox at his house anytime he wishes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am not an expert in security and i don`t know what "the thread model is". I just had a scenario in my mind, a very possible one, and I asked for potential solutions.

Comment: @giomanda as many have said before: if someone else can gain physical access to a computer, it's their computer. There are ways to hinder their progress, but treat that like a bike lock -- it doesn't stop bolt cutters.

Comment: @giomanda If you want computer to be a physical vault that can withstand physical attacks, it has to be physically constructed like a vault. This can be done, but it's expensive and complex. You need physical tamper detection linked to a circuit that physically remove sensitive data (typically the key used to encrypt the data at rest on the device) from storage. It will take a security expert to design the hardware and the software framework.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: see http://phildowd.com/?p=85

Comment: How is this not a duplicate about 6 years after Server Fault launched?

Comment: @giomanda And it's "threa**t** model". And part of what it means is that you have to thoroughly understand what you're securing and what you're securing it from. You might use SEAL Team Six to defend Fort Knox from Al Qaeda, but not to defend your new plasma TV from neighborhood thieves.

Answer (score 18):

The rule I've always worked from is that once an attacker has physical access to your host, they can eventually break into it - unless, as kasperd says, you use strong all-disk encryption with a boot password, and are willing to be there to enter it every time the host boots.

Comment: And even then, somwone with  physical access might replace the keyboard used to enter the boot password and thus learn the password ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen solution: carry around your own keyboard and tamper-proof the physical USB (or PS/2) port on the box.

Comment: @JulesMazur Counterattack: Evil Maid re-flashing the onboard firmware.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Defense: firmware password, physically, robustly-locked server box.

Comment: @JulesMazur That's somewhat high-end for protecting a "tiny Linux server which "sits" on an embedded AlixD13 board" and is small enough that it "can be stolen and placed in a pocket", don't you think? And I'm sure the firmware settings memory can be erased, triggering a reset to factory defaults, if one wants to. A power drill or metal saw is a very useful tool at times...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling you can never be too safe with roving gangs of evil maids hijacking the keyboard and/or firmware

Comment: Or take a cue from fiction and rig the device so that upon opening the case or tampering it destroys the device - which can be circumvented by rendering the trap inert. Or make your key part of the key entering system - which can be reverse engineered. Or build it so that access is impossible after it's started - which won't matter if someone has access to the electronics. Yeah, it's pretty clear that as long as a sapient tool-user tries to protect something from sapient tool-users, security is inevitably an eternal arms race. When it comes to computers, physical access is the end of security.

Answer (score 10):

The solution I'm aware of is encrypt the disk and use a TPM: [Trusted Platform Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module)

In this way there's now way do decrypt the hard drive as:

> Full disk encryption applications [...] can use this technology [TPM] to protect the keys used to encrypt the computer's hard disks and provide integrity authentication for a trusted boot pathway (for example BIOS, boot sector, etc.) A number of third party full disk encryption products also support TPM. However, TrueCrypt decided not to use it. - Wikipedia

Of course I might be wrong and the TPM can be easily cracked or I might not know other solutions.

Comment: This is correct. With a TPM, an encrypted drive and UEFI signing, it's impossible for an outsider to read the drive, or modify the bootloader to circumvent the encryption.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if USB pen exists with a TPM to add this feature to any computer.

Comment: No, because the bios has to manage the tpm.

Comment: With physical access even the TPM won't do much... you can easily sniff the data from the TPM chip when the machine is booting, or have access to the computer's entire memory without the computer noticing (and thus the TPM will "unseal" the key just fine).

Comment: @André: Not exactly easily, but yes. Even systems like the Xbox 360 got cracked. Not sure about the Xbone.

Comment: @ZanLynx a bit off-topic, but I'm pretty sure consoles don't use TPMs. They just rely on the obscurity of their architecture and that you need to physically unsolder the flash memory if you want to read their firmware.

Comment: TPM will fall to a PCI device on the bus that doesn't respond to PCI enumeration but overwrites the OS via DMA later.

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything can be cracked given the right tools and the right amount of time, that's why I upvoted Andrew's answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Full disk encryption is a good idea for laptops and small home servers.

Full disk encryption does not require a TPM.  And even a TPM is unable to protect you against a sophisticated [evil maid attack](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/10/evil_maid_attac.html).  So in order to really protect your small home Linux server (or a data center) you need appropriate other physical counter measures.

For your home use case it might be sufficient to install some creative DIY hardware which:

1. allows you to recognise any physical intrusion when you come back and
2. interupts the power supply of your computer on any physical intrusion attempt.

For journalists and whistle blowers facing some huge companies or mighty government agencies as their enemies this is probably still not secure enough.  These three letter agencies might have the [forensic equipment](http://citpsite.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/oldsite-htdocs/pub/coldboot.pdf) needed to salvage clear text from RAM [even minutes after power down](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32189/freezing-dram-for-forensics-coldboot).

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple solution: rebuild the kernel without single-user mode!

More aptly put, edit the linux kernel you're using so that mode S is remapped to whatever your default mode happens to be (3,4,5). That way, any attempt to boot into single-user mode  starts the system normally. You could probably do the same thing in the init scripts. That way there'd be no special means of entering the system without knowing the password.

Comment: If I can still get access to the grub prompt I can still change the kernel parameters to to `init=/bin/bash`. This will boot you into a root bash shell, where you can then mount `/`.

Comment: Grub can always be configured to not allow access to its shell.

Comment: As already has been pointed in other answers to this question: If a skilled attacker gets physical access to the computer then your rebuild kernel is nothing more than an old spider web on the way into the tomb containing your precious secret data jewels. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Go over and ask on the Electronics site. I am pretty sure there are embedded SOC designs which encrypt everything and once you fuse it, is "impossible" to reverse engineer.

That said, I was at a DefCon presentation where the team showed exactly how they took it apart. In a lot of cases the chips hadn't been fused, or the chip design foolishly included an unconnected debug port. On others they removed chip layers chemically and read the chip with a electron microscope scan. You'll never be safe from really dedicated hackers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to offer a different approach, if you're willing to consider destructive preventative measures.
Consider soldering a large capacity capacitor to your hdd and ram, which on tamper detection (you decide method/sensors) discharges destroying data.

This "prevents" access in the empty sense of no one can access the system afterwards. So it answers the question verbatim, while possibly completely missing your intent.

A capacitor is just an example. Other possibilities exist. The issue is weather destruction of the device (or at least the data it contains) is acceptable.

Timer based solution are also possible - unless the device can ping home every few minutes/hours/... it self destructs. Many different possibilities along this theme.

Comment: At least a rotational HDD can have its platters transplanted to another, same-model drive, and they will read just fine even if the PCB was totally destroyed. (Not sure about SSDs, but I wouldn't count on it being that much harder.) This is something data recovery companies do all the time. If you're going to do something like this with any reasonable degree of certainty (though still by no means certain!), put a small explosive inside the bowels of the drive. Works better with SSDs than with rotational HDDs for reasons unrelated to the intended destructive force.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thermite is the way to go. Explosives in an hdd requires a relatively large explosion to actually destroy the data. You'll destroy the top platter if the explosive is actually _in_ the drive, but drive platters are pretty hefty, they aren't going to just incinerate without a rather unsafe amount of explosive. Thermite burns through metal quite nice though.

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution would be to use full disk encryption, put the key on an USB stick/memory card and put the computer in a metal box with a single door which has an opening switch, along with some environmental sensors.

To boot the device once you put the USB drive in the port (on the outside of the "vault") and it reads the FDE key from there and boots the system. If the "vault" is ever opened the opening switch will reset the system, erasing the key from the memory.

If the environment allows it, you can add more sensors such as temperature, acceleration, humidity, etc. If a sudden change is detected in the values reported, the system resets, so if a thief is just trying to take the system and put it in his pocket it'll already be reset before he even disconnects it from all its cables.